# Здравствуйте, нашёл готовый код для сканирования Qr-code, но он лагает вся проблема в try{} но я не знаю как её решить,помогите! Спасибо!

Tags: c#, unity3d, qrcode

````
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using ZXing;

public class QR_WebCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WebCamTexture camTexture;
    private Rect screenRect;
    public Text Qr_Code_Value;
    void Start()
    {
        screenRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        camTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        camTexture.requestedHeight = Screen.height;
        camTexture.requestedWidth = Screen.width;
        if (camTexture != null)
        {
            camTexture.Play();
        }
    }

    void onGUI()
    {
        // drawing the camera on screen
        GUI.DrawTexture(screenRect, camTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit);
        // do the reading — you might want to attempt to read less often than you draw on the screen for performance sake
        try
        {
            IBarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
            // decode the current frame
            var result = barcodeReader.Decode(camTexture.GetPixels32(), camTexture.width, camTexture.height);
            if (result != null)
            {
                Qr_Code_Value.GetComponent<Text>().text = result.Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.LogWarning(ex.Message); }
    }

} ```
````

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом "ресурсоемкий"?

Comment: `IBarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();` можете вынести в поле и присвоить в `Start`.

Comment: `if (camTexture != null)` бесполезная проверка, потому что если там будет `null`, приложение упадет двумя строчками выше и до этой проверки дело не дойдет.

Comment: onGUI дорогой, он только для реактора.

Comment: @aepot там проблема в try{} именно из-за неё вовремя билда лагает, но не могу понять как исправить. Спасибо за предыдущие советы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь использовать конкретный декодер для QRCode. Насколько я помню, Zxing внутри перебирает все возможные штрихкоды. Так будет быстрее. Поищи по namespace, должен быть для него декодер и энкодер

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: я ищу декодеру QrCode ,больше месяца и это единственный нормальный, но у он   лагает из-за try{}. Если у вас есть другие работающие декодеры прошу вас прислать их. Спасибо!

Comment: Я же ответил, почему у тебя он ресурсоемкий. Потрудись, скачай исходник ZXing c GitHub, подключи и посмотри, что он делает, когда подсовываешь ему битмап. Он перебивает все реализации штрихкодов и пытается распознать. Я около года ковырялся в ZXing, но это давно было. Учись слушать и анализировать. Создавай опции кодирования конкретно для QR и подсовывай их и битмап конкретно энкодеру QR

Comment: Спасибо вы решили мою проблему!